# rails search returns array in dev but nil in heroku productuon environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I made a search form in which works perfectly in my dev environment but doen't work in my heroku instance. When I debug, it looks like the search result array is null in production. I made sure I have seed data in the database.

home.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag("home", method: "get") do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Search', name: nil  %>
<% end %>

<% if @search_results.any? %>
  <ul><%= render @search_results %></ul>
  <%= will_paginate @search_results %>
<% end %>
```

static_pages_controller.rb

```
def home
  if params[:search] then
    @search_results = Foo.where('bar LIKE ?', "%#{params[:search]}%").paginate(page: params[:page])
  else
    @search_results = Foo.order("bar DESC").paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
end
```

I get `@search_results.any? == false` when I run this code in heroku so no results are printed, which is not the case when I run locally. Not sure what I am missing.

Edit:

It tried querying via rails console on both dev and heroku. I used the same code on the same seed data but heroku really returns `nil`. Is it something database related, cos I know they use different databases. Here's the line:

`Foo.where('bar LIKE ?', "%baz%").paginate(page: 1)`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by peculiarities in the database.

Local installation of rails uses SQLite3 which is not case-sensitive when it comes to the WHERE clause. Heroku's PostgreSQL is case-sensitive so that when you query `Foo.where('bar LIKE ?', "%baz%")` where actually `bar == 'Baz'`, you will get results in dev but not in heroku.

It is best to use LOWER() before comparing values. In this case, replace

`Foo.where('bar LIKE ?', "%baz%")`

with

`Foo.where('LOWER(bar) LIKE LOWER(?)', "%baz%")`